# matlab installation problem from sotware centre on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, matlab

i have installed the software from the software center then it was a window prompting to enter the path of the executables files of the matlab tell me from where the files have been installed and how can i get the path of the files

Answer (score 0):

From the software center:

> This package **does not provide MATLAB**. Instead, it configures an
>   existing MATLAB installation to integrate more confortably in a Debian
>   installation.